# Box-Model for inline vs. block elements within a table td

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm using a table to display tabular data, but I need to get the sizing pixel-perfect so that the contents don't end up taking more vertical space than I have available.  Also, layout using css alone isn't feasible because I have dozens of elements.

Here is my simple test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
table, td, tr, thead, tfoot, tbody, th, tf {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border:0;
    line-height:16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr style="height:16px">
        <td>
            <span style="font-size:10pt;">Here is some text</span>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically I want the row of the table to take up only 16px, however, in this configuration it ends up taking 17px.

Inspecting the elements in FireBug it shows the span at 15px but the td and tr at 17, yet no padding, no border, etc...

[image: firebug table inline]

In IE I get the same behavior, however there is a little more information about my mysterious extra pixel or two, seems there is an offset on the span element:

[image: ie table inline offset]

Finally, I can fix the problem by turning my span element into a div, (or by making the span element display:block, or even display: table-cell which I don't really understand). So I don't really need help solving my problem, but I want to understand *why* inline elements within table cells end up taking more space then they should.  I tried google and the w3c spec but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Could it be something like the line-height of the span?</strike>

Edit: I realized that I didn't really answer the question.  I did some poking around in Firebug (I'm on a Mac, so no access to IE at the moment), and it looks like it's not the span itself that's pushing the cell's height, but that the line-height of the td does end up controlling the height of the td.  The height of the span is only 14px.  I suspect that it's the empty text node (show's in IE's dev tools) that's pushing the height.  One way to see this is to move the font-size specification up a node or two so that it will apply to the empty text node as well.  At least in FB that seems to fix it and demonstrate that the span isn't the issue. (Maybe the empty text node doesn't exist if you use a div instead? Do you even need a span or a div, or could you have your text right in the td?)

Comment: Interesting, if I look in IE developer tools at that empty text node it doesn't show it taking up any space, and when I change the span to a div it doesn't show that sneaky little empty text node.  It also works if I don't use a span or a div at all and put the text directly in the td.  Bringing the font size up to a higher level does seem to make the cell sized correctly to 16 px instead of 17, but I don't understand why that would be.  I'm wondering if there is something with inline elements inside table cells that cause this behavior (like creating that empty text node).

Comment: Does the empty text node go away if you don't put the span on its own line?

<td><span>...</span></td>

Comment: That's weird it does go away when I get rid of the white space/newlines between the td and the span tags.  I guess it's bad to put newlines in table cells? I wanted to make my markup a bit easier to read though, so that is why I had it that way.  Still boggling why it would give the cell more space for the span and not the div with the newline, I guess table cells assume when using a block level element it's going to take up the entire cell?

Comment: Update regarding the line-height: if I don't use the line-height I can't get it to size correctly with the span, and with the line-height and extra white space around the span in the td it creates the empty text text node (which apparently the line-height affects).  I guess the moral of the story for me is don't use white space and spans in table cells if you want to keep your sanity.